# NMEA format String of GPS data

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am working on the GPS application. Till now, I am getting the Location by using the LocationManager like latitude and longitude, But, I need to get the location data as NMEA 0183
like:

$GPRMC,090248,A,4745.012742,N,01304.143827,E,0.0,0.0,310710,5.3,E,A*48

how get that I dont know

if any body knows about this help to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [the specification about NMEA 0183](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA) and since you know your environment best, it shouldn't be hard to translate the data.

There are also [quite a view libraries](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=java+nmea+lib) out there, tho it seems they mostly deal with consuming data, not producing (because it's ultimately up to your needs).

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply mark but, still I am unable to get that NMEA string like $GPRMC,090248,A,4745.012742,N,01304.143827,E,0.0,0.0,310710,5.3,E,A*48this application same implemented in the Blackberry in that they have direct method like getNmeaData() in the javax.microedition.LocationBasedSystem.. here we have that Nmea state listener but it will got giving any thing like that

Comment: @Jagan: Please have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addNmeaListener%28android.location.GpsStatus.NmeaListener%29 if it helps you.